# Determine the poles of this circuit

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Determine the poles of the following circuit given that W/L is 50/0.5, Id = 1mA, Rs= 1k, Rd = 2k. Assume no channel-length modulation effects.

I decided to find the poles by inspection and examining the output node, I see that the ouput pole should be at 
$$w_{p1} = \frac{1}{R_DC_D}$$
Simarily, the input pole,
$$w_{p2} = \frac{1}{R_SC_S}$$

I have no idea how to calculate Cs or Cd. The question specifically asked me to determine the poles. Is there any way to calculate the capcacitances just by using Id and W/L as that's the only thing I haven't used yet.

Comment: It looks like a homework kind problem. I am sure that there will be a textbook or any other study material that will be explaining how to calculate \$C_S\$ and \$C_D\$

Comment: Regarding the input pole - don`t you think that the input resistance at the source node plays no role?

Comment: @LvW Input resistance is 1/gm right? But will that be in parallel with the Rs? I'm not sure about that

Comment: Yes - correct. Both are in parallel (both share one common node.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **small signal model** of a MOSFET to find the poles.

To use the **small signal**, you will need the **big signal** MOSFET calculations (`Id`, `Vds`).

You can find out here:
[Small signal models of MOS amplifiers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179592/small-signal-models-of-mos-amplifiers).

[image: The circuit to make an equivalent]

With the calculation of `Vout`, you will find the transfer function involves `Cs`, `Cd` and the resistors.

That's how your exercise is done.

Take into consideration that in big signal, the capacitors are useless.

The calculation of `gm`, the transconductance, is a step you will need.